# Find normal to plane in a point

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's suppose I have a point $P(x,y,z)$ that I know for sure it lies on a plane
$$n_x(x-x_0) + n_y(y-y_0) + n_z(z-z_0) = 0$$

How can I calculate the plane's normal vector in that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane's normal vector (in any of its point) is $\vec n=(n_x,n_y,n_z)$. By the way, if $P_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, then the equation of the plane, using scalar product is just
$$\vec n\cdot\vec{P_0P}=0$$
expressing that $\vec n\perp\vec{P_0P}$, using that the coordinates of $\vec{P_0P}$ are obtained by $P-P_0$.