# Parameterize the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which passes through the origin and is orthogonal to the plane

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the equation $y-4z = 8$, how would I go about finding the orthogonal of this equation/plane?

Also could you please try to explain it well? I'm not the best at maths.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are looking for has the following form: $$ (x,y,z)^T = s \cdot \boldsymbol{v} + P$$ where $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\boldsymbol{v}$ is the director vector of the piano which the line is orthogonal to, and $P$ is a point which the line passes through.

So, you get  $$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = s \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -4 \end{pmatrix} $$

or, equivalently $$ \{x=0, 4y +z=0 \}$$

(Note that in our case $ \boldsymbol{v} = (0, 1, -4)^T$ and $P= (0,0,0)^T$.

In addition, observe you need 2 equations to obtain a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: So would that be an appropriate answer or should I figure out what  S is?

Comment: s is a parameter, that is an appropriate answer.

Comment: if you substitute a value for $s \in \mathbb{R} $, you get a point on the line.

Comment: A possibly useful reference (explaining why $\boldsymbol{v} = (0,1,-4)^T$): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381212/find-normal-to-plane-in-a-point